# Cannot set credentials with New-Service; have to use sc.exe config – why?

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a PowerShell script that's …

- creating a local user
- adding that user to the "Log-in as Service" policy
- creating a new service that's supposed to run as the user that's been created in the previous step

When the script first creates the service using `New-Service` with default credentials and then changes the service's credentials using 'sc.exe', everything runs fine.

But when I try to provide the same credentials right in the call to `New-Service`, that call fails with exception: "Cannot create service. Reason: Improper user name or password."

**What am I doing wrong?**

#### Here's the existing code that's working

```
New-Service -Name $service.ServiceName -DisplayName $service.DisplayName -BinaryPathName "$binaryFolder" -StartupType Manual > $null

$scOutputText = & sc.exe config $service.ServiceName obj=".\$($userAccount.Username)" password="$($userAccount.Password)" | Out-String
```

#### Here's my code that's not working

```
    $params = @{
      Name           = $service.ServiceName
      DisplayName    = $service.DisplayName
      BinaryPathName = "$binaryFolder"
      StartupType    = 'Manual'
      Credential     = (New-Object -TypeName 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential' -ArgumentList $userAccount.Username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $userAccount.Password -AsPlainText -Force))
    }

    New-Service @params
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. For me (Windows 10 / PS 5.1) your "not working" code is working perfectly fine. Are you sure your `$UserAccount` variable is populated correctly in your second example (That's a long shot but your code, at first glance, have nothing wrong with it) ?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell 7.2.4. Does that perhaps make a difference? From my code examples you may find that I'm using the same variables and properties the original code does.